# how use ShoppingCart Count increment when i am click AddCartButton

Tags: jquery, css

i wanted shopping count increment when add button is click more...
how use jquery

```
<header>
  <span class="shopcountwrap">
    <i class="shopping-cart"></i>
    <div class="bage">0</div>
  </span>
</header>
```

css

```
 header{
   text-align:right;
   width:700px;
   padding-top:10px;
}
.shopcountwrap{
    position:relative;
}
.bage{
   background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    height: 20px;
    left: 1px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: -22px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
 }
```

see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/vZ66P/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

Step 1 : First declare id to div that holds count. like below:

```
  <div id="countHolder" class="bage">0</div>
```

Step 2 : Declare ids to your buttons like below:

```
           <div id="cart1" class="addcart">Add Cart</div>
```

Step 3 : Declare javascript array variable to to hold completed results:

```
    var completedIncrements =  [];
```

Step 4 : then use counter incrementor function like below in your click event handler.

```
 console.log(completedIncrements.indexOf(this.id));    

  if( completedIncrements.indexOf(this.id) == -1 ) {
  var count =   parseInt($("#countHolder").text());
   $("#countHolder").html(count + 1);

    completedIncrements.push(this.id);
}
```

Note : Dont forget to add  **parseInt** function as mentioned above; other wise count variable will be of type text instead of Integer.

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZ66P/9/) working example for you.

Comment: yes.. my freinds thank but you count is duplicate because  when i three click increment count3.. i wnat one item is one count..

Comment: @theinlwin -  updated my answer to correct duplicate edit bug.  You need to accumulate few more reputations to upvote.

Comment: The count is limited to add it one time. What about if more will be added ;)